# Append another column values to pandas column with list values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
              a   b
0  [1., 2., 3.]   1.
1  [4., 5., 6.]   2.
```

I want a 2d numpy array that takes the list from column a and appends values from column b, like so:

```
[[1., 2., 3., 1.],
 [4., 5., 6., 2.]]
```

I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
>>>np.c_[df.a, df.b]

array([[array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32), 1.],
      [[array([4., 5., 6.], dtype=float32), 2.]], dtype=object)
```

Variants of np.hstack or np.append lead to the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) with [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), as follows:

```
df.apply(lambda x:  np.append(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1).to_numpy()
```

**Result:**

```
array([array([1, 2, 3, 1]), 
       array([4, 5, 6, 2])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. For future viewers, I'll add that if you want to add more columns like this, you can try :

```df.apply(lambda x:  np.append(x['a'], (x['b'], x['c'])), axis=1).to_numpy()```